# Error al comparar caracter punto

Tags: python, comparaciones

Estoy haciendo un script en Python para obtener los primeros 3 segmentos de una dirección ip, por lo que estoy ubicando el último carácter punto. El siguiente bloque funciona bien,

```
rep1='10.253.67.124'
inc=1

while True:
    if (rep1[-inc] != "."):
        inc = inc + 1                    
    else:
        break

rep1 = rep1[:-inc+1]
print(rep1)
```

Pero cuando lo inserto en el siguiente script más grande donde leo las direcciones IP de un archivo, la comparación del carácter "." no se está realizando correctamente,

```
lin=open('D:\Info\ArchPyt\SegmentosInt.txt','r')

while True:
    rep1=lin.readline()
    rep1=rep1.strip()
    inc=1  

    while True:
        if (rep1[-inc] == '.'):  ## Esta comparación no está funcionando 
            break
        else:
            inc = inc + 1

    rep1 = rep1[:-inc+1]
    print(rep1)
    if not rep1: break
```

Ubican el error ?

Gracias.

Comment: Sería útil que pusieras una muestra del archivo SegmentosInt.txt.

Comment: Pienso que es más fácil splitear el archivo por lineas, usar el método `count()` e ir validando.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera más corta de obtener los tres primeros segmentos:

```
def tres_segmentos(ip):
    return ".".join(ip.split(".")[0:3])
```

Ejemplo:

```
for ip in ["10.0.0.1", "192.168.1.1", "255.255.255.255"]:
    print(ip, tres_segmentos(ip))
```

produce

```
10.0.0.1 10.0.0
192.168.1.1 192.168.1
255.255.255.255 255.255.255
```

Comment: 10.147.40.7
10.147.40.7
10.253.6.103
10.147.19.3
10.253.2.153
10.253.23.40
10.253.23.40

Comment: Si @aeportugal, las direcciones vienen listadas en una columna en el archivo,
10.147.40.7
10.147.40.7
10.253.6.103
10.147.19.3
10.253.2.153
10.253.23.40
10.253.23.40
.
Pero concretamente necesito darle formato al caracter punto para compararlo ?
  if (rep1[-inc] == '.'):

Por que veo que el ciclo se lo salta cuando pasa por él,